# In the event of region outage, we can failover to paired instance from Azure portal UI manually. Can we do this step programmatically?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

In the event of region outage, we can failover to paired instance from Azure portal UI manually. Can we do this step programmatically?

Can we automate the failover step? Even if not can we make somehow make it programmable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do a failover programmatically. There is a CLI command, PowerShell command, as well as various SDKs that support this.

- [az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az_iot_hub_manual_failover)
- [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/invoke-aziothubmanualfailover?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=azps-6.5.0)
- [C# SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.iothub.iothuboperationsextensions.beginmanualfailoverasync?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_IotHub_IotHubOperationsExtensions_BeginManualFailoverAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_IotHub_IIotHubOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)